# SQL : Error inserting email string into a row

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

I am writing a simple program in python that links to an SQL database for storing data, I have been testing all the queries that I want to run in the Sqlite3 shell before taking them across to python so that I know they work.

```
INSERT INTO Account (emailAddress, password) VALUES ('n.winspear1@gmail.com', 'testing');
```

I can't seem to get this one working it keeps throwing...

```
Error: near "@gmail": syntax error
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax, I'm assuming it's something quite simple, I am somewhat new to SQL so I don't know all the syntax.

Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
accountID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
emailAddress TEXT NOT NULL,
password TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the type of column emailAddress?

Comment: Sorry about that just updated with the creation code.

Comment: No worries try using double quotes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Account (emailAddress, password) VALUES ("n.winspear1@gmail.com", "testing");
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I think its possible that the text editor I'm using too is having an effect as the quotation marks are formatted when I copy paste it across, either way it works. 

Many Thanks